# How to emit final value when combining two Observable streams?

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java

Using Jake Wharton's [Managing State with RxJava](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0IKHxjkgop4) pattern.

I am combining two api calls together to be executed in parallel.

How do I emit a "success" item when both have completed?

Please see comments in code below.

Thanks!

**Main calling function:**

```
    Observable
            .just(UpdatePicEvent(userId, file))
            .compose(updatePic()) <-- Handles updating pic, emits models consumed by UI
            .mergeWith(
                    Observable
                        .just(UpdateProfileEvent(..params...))
                        .compose(updateProfile()) <-- Handles updating other settings, emits models consumed by UI
            )

            // TODO Need to add something to emit a Success() model item when both actions above have completed  

            .subscribe(...pass models to UI...)
```

**updatePic()**

```
fun updatePic(): ObservableTransformer<UpdatePicEvent, ProfileSettingsModel> {
        return ObservableTransformer {
            it.flatMap {
                api.uploadProfilePic(it.userId, it.pic)
                    .map { UpdatePicSuccessful(it) as ProfileSettingsModel }
                    .onErrorReturn { UpdatePicError(it) as ProfileSettingsModel }
                    .startWith(UpdatePicInProgress() as ProfileSettingsModel)
            }
        }
    }
```

**updateProfile()**

```
fun updateProfile(): ObservableTransformer<UpdateProfileEvent, ProfileSettingsModel> {
        return ObservableTransformer {
            it.flatMap {
                api
                    .updateUser(...params...)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .map { UpdateProfileSuccessful(it) as ProfileSettingsModel }
                    .onErrorReturn { UpdateProfileError(it) as ProfileSettingsModel }
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .startWith(UpdateProfileInProgress() as ProfileSettingsModel)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does your final success need anything from the results? What are you trying to accomplish by that final thing you emit?. Also, do you need `updatePic` and `updateProfile` to be called sequentially (it seems like you don't because you merge... but just making sure to give you a good answer)

Comment: @marianosimone "Does your final success need anything from the results?" In this case, no.  
"What are you trying to accomplish by that final thing you emit?" I'm using the sealed class `ProfileSettingsModel` to communicate the state of the transaction.  The final thing I want to emit is to signify that both API calls have completed successfully.  Thanks!

Comment: do any of the answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You're receiving two distinct `ProfileSettingsModel` you somehow need to merge. If you don't want to do this within your subscriber, you could also implement your chain with a [zip operator](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html) instead.

> combine the emissions of multiple Observables together via a specified function and emit single items for each combination based on the results of this function

```
Observable.zip(
    Observable.just(UpdatePicEvent(userId, file)).compose(updatePic())
    Observable.just(UpdateProfileEvent(..params...)).compose(updateProfile())
    mergePicAndProfile)
```

Where `mergePicAndProfile` is a `BiFunction` receiving the both results and emitting a single entity.

Answer (score 0):

Given your comment on the original question, [`concat`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/concat.html) could help you. The relevant part of the docs say:

> The Concat operator concatenates the output of multiple Observables so that they act like a single Observable, with all of the items emitted by the first Observable being emitted before any of the items emitted by the second Observable (and so forth, if there are more than two).
>
> Concat waits to subscribe to each additional Observable that you pass to it until the previous Observable completes.

Implementation:

```
Observable.mergeDelayError(
    Observable.just(UpdatePicEvent(userId, file)).compose(updatePic()),
    Observable.just(UpdateProfileEvent(userId, params)).compose(updateProfile())    
)
    .concatWith(Observable.just(AllSuccessful()))  // Or whatever
    .onErrorReturn { when (it) {
        is UpdatePicException -> UpdatePicError(it)
        is UpdateProfileException -> UpdateProfileError(it)
    }}
```

There are two key things for this to work:

1. You need to replace the `onErrorReturn` in both `updatePic` and `updateProfile` transformers so they actually emit an error when they fail (probably with something like `onErrorResumeNext { Observable.error(MyTypeOfException()) }`. If you don't do this, there's no way for the stream to know if there was an error or not (as wrapping the error in an item makes it indistinguishable from a success)
2. Use `mergeDelayError` to let each stream continue independently of the other. If you just use `merge`, the first one to fail will prevent the other from continuing.

(note that I modified your original code slightly to make it, IMHO, more readable)

Comment: This works when the 2 calls are successful (and thanks for the improved syntax).  However when there's an error, it is still emitting `AllSuccessful'.

Comment: Oh, didn't realize that you were wrapping the errors in actual results inside the transformers. See my edit to see if that helps

Comment: Thanks for your help.  However the transformers are used elsewhere as individual calls, so changing them sort of defeats the purpose.  I was looking for a way to combine them without having to write a new chain.  Seems like maybe I should just carry state of the Success emissions and check for them inside `subscribe` ?

Comment: I guess so. If you are encapsulating the errors in emissions, then you won't be able to distinguish an overall success from a failure, unless you somehow check for them in the subscribe.